# Linking Primary Keys and Foreign keys through a disjointed eer schema

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, erd

[image]

Hello,
Having a massive difficulty converting a disjointed EER diagram to mysql
I believe the User entity has been setup correctly, just wondering how I would link User to a buyer/seller? Would I add a buyer/seller ID on the user then link that as a FK?

Here is mysql below.. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

[image]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Where & how are you 1st stuck following what textbook/reference? It defines your EER method & notation (which you don't give) & how to express in DDL. This just asks us to rewrite it.

Comment: I made the EER diagram myself.. I was just trying to see if it was correct/better alternatives..

Comment: That is not a reason not to act on my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model shows that the subclasses `Buyer` and `Seller` are disjoint specializations of the `User` entity (A seller cannot be a buyer, and a buyer cannot be a seller) denoted by the circle with 'D'. Depending on your situation, you *could* challenge this design (can someone sell while having bought in the past?).

Each of these entities have different attributes not common to one another, except the ones shared by a `User`.

There are different ways of modeling this, but a what you might need for instance, is to have a `Buyer` table and `Seller` table. Both of these tables would then contain a foreign key to the `User` table.

A less normalized alternative is to have a `User` table that contains attributes from both subclasses, but then some of the attributes would be NULL if they're not applicable. They would then be distinguishable by a `Role` attribute.

Advised reading: [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: Transformations between designs involving subtypes have nothing to do with (either of the 2 basic senses of) database normalization.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your help, in the end I made buyer and seller tables with the same attributes and then linked them by foreign key back to the USER ID as otherwise I wouldn't have been able to access the attributes..